# How to efficiently convert a multi json array to list in python avoiding for loops

Tags: python, json

I have a json array in the form

```
[
  {
    "id": 1, "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 2, "name": "b"
  }
]
```

I want to get all the names in a single list.
Like the output list should contain

```
["a","b"]
```

I can do it with a for loop. But the for loop is taking so much time.. Is there an efficient way to do this in python

```
import json
jsonString='''[
  {
    "id": 1, "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 2, "name": "b"
  }
]'''
jsonArray=json.loads(jsonString)    
nameList=[]

for eachJson in jsonArray:
    nameList.append(eachJson['name'])
```

Is there a faster way to do this as the for loop takes a lot of time with big data

Comment: can you define "so much time"?  and how many elements are you talking about?  the above will take a few microseconds

Answer (score 2):

First of all the fast/slow is quite relative, you should provide more details about your expectations (time, size of data etc...).
But you can use the list comprehension instead of for loop. It is more faster.

**Example:**

```
import json

jsonString = """[
  {
    "id": 1, "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 2, "name": "b"
  }
]"""
nameList = [eachJson["name"] for eachJson in json.loads(jsonString)]
```

**Time with your implementation:**

```
>>> time python test.py

real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.016s
```

**Time with list comprehension:**

```
>>> time python test.py

real    0m0.026s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.012s
```

As you can see above the real time is almost half with list comprehension.

**EDIT:**

Or you can measure the execution time with the `time` Python module.

**For example:**

```
import time

start = time.time()
print("hello")
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

**I have measured the two implementation with `time` module:**

```
>>> python for_loop.py
6.103515625e-05
>>> python list_comprehension.py
4.60147857666e-05
```

**NOTE:**

You can find more-more faster Json parser modules then built-in `json` module. Probably the `yajl` module is most fast module. Details: https://github.com/rtyler/py-yajl/

```
yajl        serialize: 0.180  deserialize: 0.182  total: 0.362
simplejson  serialize: 0.840  deserialize: 0.490  total: 1.331
stdlib json serialize: 2.812  deserialize: 8.725  total: 11.537
```

A comparator of Python Json parsers: https://github.com/rtyler/py-yajl/blob/master/compare.py

Or you can check the `ultrajson` module. It is also faster than built-in parser: https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson